# Google Analytics Server Side

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics, download, asp.net-4.0, tracking

I'd like to track downloads of a PDF on my website.

I'd prefer it to be some kind of event tracking with Google Analytics.

I've been reading up on the [Mobile SDK with ASP.Net](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/mobileWebsites.html#asp) but it still seems like you need to execute some javascript client side for it to work properly.

Anybody have any ideas for a completely server side Google Analytics implementation?

I'm hoping for some kind of HTTP Post to `ga.js?useragent=THIS&ip=THAT&cookie=SOMETHING`...

Comment: Why don't you write a simple web app that serves the PDF as a stream and do the counting yourself?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing unfortunately...

Comment: Can people download your pdf without visit your site?

Comment: @greg I can have a download page and track it that way, but I'd rather track it server side so that even if someone had the direct file URL, I could still track the download.